# Removing only files with extension(".pdf") in R

Tags: r

I want to remove any file which have extension of ".pdf" in r for the current working directory

```
file.remove(".pdf")
    if(file.exists(paste0("Pic,".pdf"))){
      clsfile<-paste0(Pic,".pdf")
        unlink(clsfile, recursive=TRUE)
        
       

      }
```

Comment: Try: `file.remove(list.files(pattern = "*.pdf"))`

Comment: It says permission denied

Comment: How to use unlink to delete all pdf files?